# composer: package can not be found on each environment

Tags: composer-php

I was trying to install a composer package for Magento2 using `composer require magestore/storelocator-magento2`. In my local Vagrant box as well on my laptop the package could be found and was installed, whereas on a dev-server the same package could not be found.

My question is, **which differences in the system setup or composer setup could be the reason, that an existing package cannot be found?**
The composer.json and thus the stability settings are identical in all environments.

```
# machine 1

$ composer --version
Composer version 1.6.3 2018-01-31 16:28:17

$ composer require magestore/storelocator-magento2
Using version ^1.0 for magestore/storelocator-magento2


# machine 2

$ composer --version
Composer version 1.6.3 2018-01-31 16:28:17

$ composer require magestore/storelocator-magento2
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                                                                             
Could not find a matching version of package magestore/storelocator-magento2.
```

Comment: I see that `magestore/storelocator-magento2` is not available on packagist.org. Is it installed from a private repo of some kind? Do you have proper credentials set up on machine 2 to access it?

Comment: @EdiModrić There is an additional repository defined in each composer.json: `"repositories": [ { "type": "composer", "url": "https://repo.magento.com/" } ],`; no other private repository is in use here;

Comment: Do you need credentials for `https://repo.magento.com` ? It's hard to answer the question without access to `composer.json` file of `magestore/storelocator-magento2` and your PHP and Composer versions.